# Control of listview column order

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a form with quite a few controls on it. The data presented is selected by a query. At occasions I want to change from form view to list view by VBA, however MS Access seems to have it's own ideas on the column order.

How can I control and make sure that the columns appear in a senseful way, e.g. by always having the key (in my case the article number) in the first column followed by the main attributes?

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of the information found here: http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=203904 you should simply be able to just set the column order for all of your fields.  Example they used:

```
Me.tblxx_Gemeinde_ID.ColumnOrder = 1
Me.vorschlag.ColumnOrder = 2
Me.tbl_Auftrag_ID.ColumnOrder = 3
Me.tblxx_Haushaltsabschnitte_ID.ColumnOrder = 4
Me.tblxx_Taetigkeit_id.ColumnOrder = 5
```

So I would just add something like this into your VBA function you use to change to list view.  (This answer is based off of the assumption that by list view you mean datasheet view.)

Comment: @OlManVBA No problem, just be forewarned that it seems like in MS Access 2010 it can have issues with the ordering of unbound boxes.